# BSOD on host machine when using virtualbox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, bsod

I'm getting a BSOD (Critical_Structure_Corruption) on host after 30-90 minutes of using a vm. It never happens when not running a vm.

Guest:

- Virtualbox 6.0.6r130049 (Qt5.6.2)
- RAM: 3192MB
- Enabled I/O APIC
- CPU: 1
- Execution Cap: 80%
- Enabled PAE/NX
- Paravirtualization Interface: Legacy
- Enabled VT-x/AMD-v
- Enabled Nested Paging
- Video Memory: 56MB
- Monitor Count: 1
- Graphics Controller: VBoxSVGA
- Disabled 3D Acceleration and 2D Video Acceleration
- Storage: SATA 32GB Dynamically Allocated
- Guest OS: Windows 10 64 bits PRO
- Guest Additions not installed (I tried with them installed, same problem).

Host:

- Host OS: Windows 10 64 bits PRO
- RAM: 16GB
- CPU: i5 8400
- GPU: GTX 1060 6GB

I don't know what to do, I can't use any vm. I tried searching about this error but got results that didn't help.

Comment: For starters, you have very little RAM to be running VMs.

Comment: Nono, that's the setup for the guest. My bad I forgot the title, 1 sec I will fix it

Comment: Did you disable Hyper-V feature and hypervisor in bcdedit?

Comment: I checked, it is disabled. Should I enable it? (I already enabled it on the BIOS)

Comment: I mean, I enabled vt-x in BIOS.

Comment: I found this: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2060019 But I have no idea on how to apply this to VirtualBox

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/790216/how-to-avoid-critical-structure-corruption-errors-with-virtualbox-inside-vmware

Comment: Yep, I already have the latest version, only 1 cpu. And I'm not using vmware so I don't know how to do that on VirtualBox since it doesn't have that option on the vm settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that this was causing the issue: https://github.com/hfiref0x/VBoxHardenedLoader/issues/4
As the link explains, if using the VBoxHardenedLoader from that page on Windows 10 it will be unstable unless you Code Sign the driver.

Comment: What is "this"? What steps did you follow to resolve it? While a link may be minimally helpful it gives little useful information here on this site. If the link dies or the page is deleted or moved for whatever reason then your answer may become useless.

Comment: Done, added explanation. Sorry!